# Java JTable -- Custom Row Sorter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have a JTable that loads data from a database and then generates a summary row at the bottom of the table. I want the user to be able to sort the table, but I'd like the summary row to always remain at the bottom of the table.

I've been trying to create a custom TableRowSorter, but I'm having some trouble figuring it out and getting it to do what I want.

Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: For sooner help post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/);

Comment: You might start with the examples near [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! (I didn't post any code because there really wasn't any to post -- wasn't quite sure where to even start with the row sorter stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a class which holds whether the value is a summary or not.
Something like this

```
public class SummarizedValue {
  public Integer value;
  public boolean summarized;
  public String toString() { 
    return null == value? "" : value.toString();
  }
}

public class SummaryComparator implements Comparator<SummarizedValue> {
  public int compare(SummarizedValue v1, SummarizedValue v2) {
    if (v1.summarized) return 1;
    if (v2.summarized) return -1;
    return v1.value.compareTo(v2.value);
  }
}

public class SummaryBackComparator implements Comparator<SummarizedValue> {
  public int compare(SummarizedValue v1, SummarizedValue v2) {
    if (v1.summarized) return 1;
    if (v2.summarized) return -1;
    return v2.value.compareTo(v1.value);
  }
}
```

You need to display the objects of class `SummarizedValue` in your column and your row sorter should return `SummaryComparator`. Also your need to override toggle behaviour in RowSorter to use `SummaryBackComparator`.

Comment: +1 but I think that for Java6 isn't required to create any Comparator, I see some special cases but ....  `value? "" : value.toString(); :-)`